# C# step-by-step tutorial with sample code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

Could anyone suggest a good step-by-step C# MVC4 tutorial? I need to learn this language but I could not find any really great tutorial with sample code and explanation yet. I should create web sites with these things but it's really different from PHP what I have used till now.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Start with http://www.asp.net/mvc

Comment: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow_

Comment: You should have a look at [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Microsoft's [MVC Music Store](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store) is a pretty classic example.

Comment: here's for [MVC 4](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-fundamentals)

Answer (score 0):

You can also visit the channel9 to see different kind of vidoes http://channel9.msdn.com/search?term=mvc